# Python Regex for pattern matching

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to parse the sample input test_string1 as below:

```
import re
TEST_STRING1 = """Using definitions from (yyyy/mm/dd): 2016/6/8
The following files are collected:
  File: Test.exe
    Source: Google
    avping blob: 123123

Downloaded 3 Files
"""
def fun():

    regex_exp = re.compile(r"File:\s(?P<File>[^\n\r\t]+?)[\n\r\t\s]*?"
                           r"Source:\s(?P<Source>.*)[^\w\d]*?"
                           r"avping\sblob:\s(?P<Avping_blob>([A-F]|[a-f]|[0-9]){6})")
    result = {}
    result['Files'] = []
    for m in re.finditer(regex_exp, TEST_STRING1):
        result['Files'].append(m.groupdict())
    print result
if __name__ == "__main__":
    fun()
```

Output of the Above code is :

```
{'Files': [{'Source': 'Google', 'File': 'Test.exe', 'Avping_blob': '123123'}]}
```

I want to make some fields in Input optional such as avping blob:
Like

```
TET_STRING1 = """Using definitions from (yyyy/mm/dd): 2016/6/8
The following files are collected:
  File: Test.exe
    Source: Google

Downloaded 3 Files
"""
```

In that casa above regex return no match.

I have updated the regex as

```
regex_exp = re.compile(r"(File:\s(?P<File>[^\n\r\t]+?)[\n\r\t\s]*?"
                           r"Source:\s(?P<Source>.*)[^\w\d]*?"
                           r"|avping\sblob:\s(?P<Avping_blob>([A-F]|[a-f]|[0-9]){6}))")
```

by adding `|` before last line. But then It gives 2 matches with OR as

```
{'Files': [{'Source': 'Google', 'File': 'Test.exe', 'Avping_blob': None}, {'Source': None, 'File': None, 'Avping_blob': '123123'}]}
```

How should I write regex that will match the pattern for both input types (with and without optional fields)?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an optional non-capturing group and use `[^\w\d]*` greedy version:

```
(File:\s(?P<File>[^\n\r\t]+?)[\n\r\t\s]*?Source:\s(?P<Source>.*)[^\w\d]*(?:avping\sblob:\s(?P<Avping_blob>[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}))?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yD8dS9/2)

In your code:

```
regex_exp = re.compile(r"(File:\s(?P<File>[^\n\r\t]+?)[\n\r\t\s]*?"
                       r"Source:\s(?P<Source>.*)[^\w\d]*"    # <- Here ? is removed
                       r"(?:avping\sblob:\s(?P<Avping_blob>[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}))?)")
                         ^^^                                               ^
```

Also, `([A-F]|[a-f]|[0-9]){6})` = `(?P<Avping_blob>[A-Fa-f0-9]{6})`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: I am getting result as '{'Files': [{'Source': 'Google', 'File': 'Test.exe', 'Avping_blob': None}]}' in both the cases in python code. avping_blob is NONE in both the cases

Comment: Try the updated version. So, the second one can be NONE, right?